# ¿Por qué me salta error al usar el módulo random?

Tags: python, modulos

Básicamente me dice que no puedo usar el método `random.radint` desde una **`built_in_funtion_or_method`**, y la verdad no se porque.

El código es este:

```
import random
from random import *
def tirarDados(numeroDeDados,numeroDeCaras):
    resultados = list([])
    for i in range(numeroDeDados):
        resultados.append(random.randint(1,numeroDeCaras))
    return resultados
```

Comment: Es muy probable que el error tenga relación con los argumentos que recibe esa función. Podrías agregar un código que tenga el mismo error y pase argumentos a esa función por favor? Así, será más facil (o posible) responderte

Comment: Cuando llamas a una función, lo haces como función(a, b,...). Esos a, b, etc son argumentos.

Comment: no se como crear un codigo con errores a proposito. pero si te llegase a servir, el error es algo como esto: AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'randint'

Comment: En ese caso, toma tu código original y elimina, por prueba, error y sentido común, las partes no relevantes al error ni al funcionamiento del programa

Comment: Esto lo llamamos "ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable". No tengo el link a mano, pero en el centro de ayuda se explica como funciona

Comment: muchisimas gracias, al final el problema estaba en la segunda linea: 'from random import *' y al borrarla todo funciona perfectamente

Answer (score 0):

```py
import random

def tirarDados(numeroDeDados, numeroDeCaras):
    resultados = []
    for i in range(numeroDeDados):
        resultados.append(random.randint(1, numeroDeCaras))
    return resultados

dados = tirarDados(3, 6)
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Puedes ser más claro? Una respuesta que solo contiene código no se entiende por sí sola. Podrías simplemente haber copiado el mismo código que está en la pregunta.

Comment: Hola quantarmy, bienvenido  y gracias por tu colaboración, las respuestas que son solo código, son consideradas de baja calidad, te sugiero que edites la tuya, y expliques de que forma resuelve el problema planteado, así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.

Answer (score 0):

No se el error exacto que te daba, pero siento probable que sea:

```
builtin_function_or_method has no atribute 'randint'
```

##### la variable random no es lo que creias

En los comentarios, mencionaste que eliminaste una linea `from random import *`

Pero por que esto resolvió el problema?

Los import, guardan lo que indiques en variables.
Por ejemplo, `import random` crea la variable random y guarda el modulo en una variable del mismo nombre.

`from random import *` es equivalente a aplicar `from random import [atributo del modulo]` a cada atributo o variable que contiene el modulo y que cumple criterios que no vienen al tema.

Entre las cosas que se importan con ese `*`, curiosamente hay un objeto que representa una función o método escrito en c (built_in_function_or_method, c es el lenguaje de programación que usa el interprete de Python) y se llama `random`.

**Por lo tanto, la variable que antes era el modulo random pasa a referenciar a aquel objeto.**

##### No importes lo mismo de dos maneras distintas

Aunque en programación hay varias maneras de hacer lo mismo, hay casos donde usar varias formas a la vez resulta redundante. Y la redundancia causa confusión al leer el código y trabajo innecesario para el programa. Esto también aplica a los imports. Te pregunto ¿Querés usar el modulo random a través de una variable del mismo nombre, o guardar cada cosa del modulo random en tu programa principal?